# Same SQL not ending properly

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having trouble with the same ORA-00933. My code is below:

```
SELECT cu.customername
FROM customer cu
WHERE cu.customerid = salestranscation.customerid AND
salestransaction.tid = soldvia.tid AND
soldvia.productid = product.productid
product.productprice >= 150;
```

Essentially I am trying to collect the customers who bought product greater than or equal to 150.

Thanks

Comment: You don't have salestransaction table mentioned in your query

Comment: Basically your query is missing tables in "from clause" best way would be take the sql and run in your db first if it succeeds the use it in your code

Comment: Ok. I added the tables into the FROM aspect.

    SELECT cu.customername
    FROM customer cu, salestransaction st, soldvia sv, product pro
    WHERE cu.customerid = st.customerid AND
    st.tid = sv.tid AND
    sv.productid = pro.productid
    pro.productprice >= 150;

I am still receiving the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing `AND` in where clause
Your query should be:

```
SELECT cu.customername
FROM customer cu
WHERE cu.customerid = salestranscation.customerid AND
salestransaction.tid = soldvia.tid AND
soldvia.productid = product.productid AND
product.productprice >= 150;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your where clause is wrong. 
Take a look at
http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00933_sql_command_ended.htm
http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00933.php